# Check engine light & traction control light on 2011 Mazda Cx7,when it rains

Tags: mazda, cx7

Took it to shop & they could not find the problem. Car will only do 10 mph when lights are on. Had it taken to Mazda dealer, next day they called & said nothing was wrong. next time it rained same thing, will not run. A 2011 Mazda Cx7.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: [Check Engine Light. What information do I need to provide?](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1473/675)